# NFT on Opensea #Alchemy

Tags: alchemy

I followed all steps in 3 parts of this tutorial https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-view-nft-in-metamask/ I also registered NFT in Metamask wallet. Wallet adress  0xB6157cEAAAcA2850D55EbBF82b673B1A01e2Ef28 , NFT contract adress  0x3b9c3f002303bf3f00d7cc226b5085195eebfdca
Can I see this NFT on Opensea?

Comment: Please excuse me for repeating the question. I'm new. I will be glad for any help